# Choosing Javascript Libraries When Designing a Web App

Tags: web-applications, javascript

Even as an experienced developer (mainly PHP & Java/Android), moving into the world of web app development has been a little overwhelming. I am certainly not the first to say that the number of Javascript Frameworks available is overwhelming.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs

http://www.infoq.com/research/top-javascript-mvc-frameworks

http://www.netmagazine.com/features/essential-javascript-top-five-mvc-frameworks

But as any web app developer knows, the Javascript libraries available go far beyond MV* Frameworks. A few really cool & useful libraries that I have found include:

[Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) / [Angujar](http://angularjs.org/) / [Ember](http://emberjs.com/) (MV* Frameworks)

[JQuery](http://jquery.com/) / [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) / [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) / [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) (DOM Manipulation)

[Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) / [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) / [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) (Templating)

[Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) (AMD)

[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) (Multiple)

[Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) (Testing)

[JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) (UI)

This is by no means intended to be a complete list. I'm sure there are hundreds of other good libraries out there. What's more, these are all general-purpose libraries (not graphing, animation, math, etc).

My question is, from a **design** standpoint, how should a new web app developer go about choosing which general-purpose libraries to use for an app? More specifically, what **types** of libraries should a new web app developer look at using?

Comment: `My question is, from a design standpoint, how should a new web app developer go about choosing which general-purpose libraries to use for an app?` In my humble opinion, none. Not all tools apply to all situations the same way. First you start developing a site then encounter a problem or a tedious process. Then you look for a library or framework which helps you solve the issue or makes your live easier with the tedious process you had issues with. Don't just use a framework cause someone else says so.

Comment: Mind you, having said that. It is good to know how to use at least the most popular frameworks or even a little about all of them to be aware what they offer and what problems they try to solve. That will help you in choosing the right tool for the right job and that is what will make a great developer. Not picking 1 library and that's it.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl you're right. I would recommend that you dig down and get your hands dirty and learn raw JavaScript then you can pick and choose which libraries are best for a given web app, or a given portion of a web app. My absolute opinion is to use raw JavaScript any and everywhere that you can. Sometimes if I use one of the libraries, for a quick fix or demo purposes, I'll comment the exact spot in my code so that I can remove that portion of the library out of my code later on.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl "It is good to know how to use at least the most popular frameworks" -- like what? JQuery, of course, but Backbone/Angular? Jasmine? Any UI libraries?

Comment: @MattRobertson: I suppose that was a bit of a blanket statement. While jQuery is obvious for it's popularity other frameworks may not be so obvious if you are not sure what to look for. I personally read Web Designer and the .NET magazine which usually highlights the "What's hot at the moment" frameworks. If I would not do that then sure, you are right, I probably would not know where to start. I suppose I would start by looking at the question count on SO for each framework and start looking into the ones which have a lot of traffic.

Comment: Great suggestions! I suppose really all I am looking for is a place to start looking...

Comment: @AlumCloud.Com: I started learning JavaScript through jQuery and had a hard time. Took me a while before I fully understood, which methods came from jQuery and which were not. Simple things like setTimeout I assumed was a jQuery method. So I decided to re-think my tactics. While having to use jQuery in work I started reading the MDN and look at books like JavaScript the good parts and so on. The best thing I ever did was force myself to only use pure JavaScript when working on pet-projects at home. I know appreciate jQuery but also realized you don't need to use it by default just-cause.

Comment: JavaScript is hard, let's go shopping ;)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of your web app and what type of web app your developing. I've found from a lot of experience that the concept of JavaScript libraries are not like those of JAVA and or .NET. JavaScript libraries are a moving target and they're always changing, it is obvious that the authors of these libraries are in a rush to be the first to the market pushing their libraries as a way to ease JavaScript development, because their library cuts down on development time of some specific operations.
While they're libraries do cut down on development time if you're developing a large JavaScript web app you'll find that these libraries will end up costing you more time in the end, because you've got the expense of learning the library then the updates they're always doing.

For large apps use the libraries at a minimum for user interaction and don't integrate them into the core of your application.

For small web apps it doesn't matter.

JQuery has got some age and they've really got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

it really matter how you want to design the entire web application.

Now days bowsers are became more powerful and enriched with Javascript and HTML5.  Most of the developers want to utilize power of browser and make server free out of UI logic/generation.  In this case developers could create a single page application(like gmail) and consume the web services(JSON,XML,  JSONP).  To develop such application following can be the reason to choose any UI library

1. MV/MVC: Segregate/arranging the code in MV/MVC layers.
2. Tempting Lib : The View layer can utilize available tempting
       libraries(DRY)
3. AMD: Can be used to load files and module on demand(optimization)
4. Testing Framework: Jsmine, to write test cases
5. Dom Manipulation: Most of the MC/MVC libs come with dom utility if
       not then they depend on other available libraries like
       Jquery/Dojo/YUI etc(utilities to avoid reinventing the wheel)

Apart from above if UI requires simple dom manipulation, some ajax, validations and UI effects with cross browser support, then JS libraries like jQuery/Prototype/Dojo are useful.